# Is the ring $ R = \{ f \in \mathbb{C}[x,y] \mid {\nabla f}(0,0) = (0,0) \} $ Noetherian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noetherian

> **Question:** Is the ring $ R = \{ f \in \mathbb{C}[x,y] \mid {\nabla f}(0,0) = (0,0) \} $ Noetherian?

I guess it isn’t Noetherian as I suspect that
$$
(x y + y^{2}), \quad
(x y + y^{2},x^{2} y + y^{3}), \quad
(x y + y^{2},x^{2} y + y^{3},x^{3} y + y^{4}), \quad \ldots
$$
is an ascending chain of ideals. I don’t know whether this is right or not.

Thanks!

Comment: Your ideals are $I_n=(y)(x+y,x^2+y^2,\cdots,x^n+y^n)$. Since $x^k+y^k$ is a symmetric polynomial in the variables $x$ and $y$ it can be written as $f(x+y,xy)$, but $xy=\frac{1}{2}((x+y)^2-(x^2+y^2))$ is an element of $(x+y,x^2+y^2)$, so we get $I_2=I_3=I_4=\cdots$. BTW, your subring is $\Bbb C+(x^2,xy,y^2)$

Comment: @seaturtles, the subring is the sum of that ideal and the constants.

Comment: @Mariano Oops, yes.

Comment: @sea turtles @ Mariano Suárez-Alvarez, Thanks!

Comment: Exact duplicate of [this previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/63579/115654) (although this one is better titled)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your ring $R$ is generated as an algebra over $\mathbb C$ by the monomials of $\mathbb C[x,y]$ of degree $2$ and $3$, of which there are 7. That means there is a surjection from $\mathbb C[z_1,\dots,z_7]$ onto your ring, which is therefore noetherian.

Let us check my claim about $R$ being generated by those monomials. If a polynomial is in $R$ then its linear terms are zero, and therefore all the monomials it has also belong to $R$. It follows that $R$ is generated as a complex vector space by all the monomials it contains. Now you can easily check that a monomial $x^iy^j$ is in $R$ if $i+j>1$ or $i+j=0$. Such a monomial can we written as a product of monomials of degree $2$ and $3$.

Comment: @user26857,   well, that is *exactly* the same as saying that the ring is generated by the monomials of degre $2$ and $3$ in $\mathbb C[x,y$], which is what I said: it is not any clearer! :-)